# Notification when activity is(not) at the top of stack (resumed/paused)

Tags: android, android-activity, intentfilter

Is there any way to be notified (e.g. using broadcast receiver) when some activity is or is not at the top of a stack (displayed on the screen)?

I would like to know when lets say google navigation is being launched and closed (resumed/paused). This means I can't modify application and send appropriate intent in the onResume/onPause methods.

I have scanned list of system Intents but didn't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure if the app developer didn't build in such an api for you to hook into you are out of luck